# php read and extract data from text file

Tags: php

This is to upload and print a text file. Now, this txt file contains details of people booking and comes via email and looks something like this:

```
some text (always the same)
= ================
text again
name   : Mr F Someone
address: Somewhere
...
...
more same text
```

The problem is there are no delimiters. and I want to grab the data like "Mr", "F", "Someone",... and then put each one of them in an input field of a form. I tried something like this:

```
    $section_a = file_get_contents($up_folder, NULL, NULL, 508, 2);
    echo '<input type="text" name="Title" value="'.$section_a.'">';
```

but if it is "Miss" instead of "Mr" then it is a problem, same as the length of the name and so on. And there is more than one "booking" in a file. So, is there a way of getting the details of each booking out of the file to put each time in a form?

```
<?php
    if($_FILES['userfile']['error'] > 0){
        echo 'Houston, we have a problem: ';
        switch($_FILES['userfile']['error'])
        {    
            case 1: echo 'file too big'; break;
            case 2: echo 'file too big'; break;
            case 3: echo 'incomplete upload'; break;
            case 4: echo 'uplad error'; break;
        }
        exit;
    }
    if($_FILES['userfile']['type'] != 'text/plain'){
        echo 'Ooh noes! File is not plain text dude!';
        exit;
    }
    $up_folder = 'upload/'.$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])){
        if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $up_folder)){
            echo 'cannot move file';
            exit;
        }
    }
    else{
        echo 'error: ';
        echo $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        exit;
    }
    echo 'file upload successful<br>';

    $fp = fopen($up_folder, 'r');
    $contents = fread($fp, filesize($up_folder));
    fclose($fp);

    $contents = strip_tags($contents); 
    $fp = fopen($upfile, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $contents);
    fclose($fp);

    echo 'Uploaded file content: <br> <br>';
    echo $contents;
?>
```

Comment: `explode` on `'\n'` after that explode on `' '` and you shall find what you are looking for

Comment: This is very complex, because there are so many ways that people can write names. They might leave out prefixes like `Mr` entirely, they might have middle names, etc.

Comment: The more control over the text file's formatting that you have, the better. You can force things like pseudo-XML tags. You've opened a can of jigglers that you may not like dealing with later.

Comment: @Barmar No, the prefixes are always there and the first letter of the irst name too and the last name is there. so there is a pattern

Comment: are all fields named and separated by a `:`? Is address always in multiple lines like that? It seems you can easily read the file line by line and explode on `:` for field values and then further explode on space for each value separated however for address you will need further verifications to find where the next field starts. **You should extremely consider moving into a proper database.**

Comment: i have a database for the information of the people that book on our site directly. i just wanted to find an automatic way for the ones that we get from an external source. but i think it seems to be a mammoth. thanks anyway folks

Comment: As others have commented, you can just explode on `:` to separate the field name and value, and then explode the value on space to get the words. Should be very simple code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fetch = ['name','address'];
$output = [];

$fp = fopen($file, 'r');
while(!feof($fp) && count($output) !== count($fetch)) {
    $line = fgets($line);
    list($prefix, $value) = explode(':', $line, 2);
    $prefix = strtolower(trim($prefix));
    foreach($fetch as $f) {
        if($prefix === $f) {
            $output[$f] = trim($value);
            break;
        }
    }
}
fclose($fp);

print_r($output);
```